# CSS Text Slideshow: After Second Slide, All Slides Merge. How to Fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

Actually, I am currently working on making a pure CSS text slideshow as a topbar in my site's header.

The code I have created is:

HTML

```
<div class="slider">
    <p class="slide">30% to 60% off Sitewide  |  Extra 30% off Sale</p>
    <p class="slide">20% off Refer a Friend</p>
    <p class="slide">Extra 10% off on Prepaid Orders</p>
    <p class="slide">Clearance Sale is LIVE</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider{position:relative;height:40px;padding:0 10px;background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:13px}

.slider .slide{position:absolute;animation:slider 16s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1) infinite;transform:translateX(-5%);transition:all 4s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);opacity:0}

.slider.paused .slide{animation-play-state:paused}

.slider .slide:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s}

.slider .slide:nth-child(3){animation-delay:12s}

.slider .slide:nth-child(4){animation-delay:16s}

@keyframes slider{
0%{transform:translateX(-5%);opacity:0}
7.5%,33%{transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}
75%,100%{transform:translateX(5%);opacity:0}
}
```

JQuery

```
$(".slider").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("paused");
    }
);
```

Now, everything works fine until I use only 2 slides. But, as I increase the number of slides to 4. First 2 sides does the transition perfectly and then all slides merge and show one behind one, at the same time. I believe the problem is with animation-delay or something. But, I could not figure out what.

I tried to change animation-delay property and see if it works, but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When you increase the number of slides, increase the total animation duration and set animation-delay for each slide. You will also have to adjust the keyframes. For 2 slides, keyframe points will be different, and for 3 or 4 slides, the animation gap among slides will be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a separate animation for each slide. Divide 100% by the number of slides - this will be the keyframe when one slide is animated.

In general, it is not very convenient to do it manually. I would write some generator that would output css animation code. Because when changing the number of slides, everything will have to be recalculated.

Example for 4 slides:

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider:hover .slide {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  animation: slide1 6s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide1 {
  0% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-5%); }
  5%, 20% { opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); }
  25% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(5%); }
}
    
.slide:nth-child(2) {
  animation: slide2 6s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide2 {
  25% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-5%); }
  30%, 45% { opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(5%); }
}
    
.slide:nth-child(3) {
  animation: slide3 6s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide3 {
  50% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-5%); }
  55%, 70% { opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); }
  75% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(5%); }
}
    
.slide:nth-child(4) {
  animation: slide4 6s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide4 {
  75% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-5%); }
  80%, 95% { opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(5%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <p class="slide">30% to 60% off Sitewide  |  Extra 30% off Sale</p>
  <p class="slide">20% off Refer a Friend</p>
  <p class="slide">Extra 10% off on Prepaid Orders</p>
  <p class="slide">Clearance Sale is LIVE</p>
</div>
```

---

**Update:** It became interesting, so I created such a "[**generator**](https://imhvost.github.io/76847170.html)", maybe it will be useful to someone .